# What causes proxy to stop working in a React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, fastapi, http-status-code-500

My React/FastAPI application had proxy

`proxy": "http://localhost:8000`

in my package.json working fine but now the proxy doesn't work and I get back

`Internal Server Error (500) Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0`

I tried

`http://127.0.0.1:8000`

for proxy and the same problem.

I checked the FastAPI backend and everything works fine. If I put the whole path inside fetch, then there is no problem.

I know if the error said `Unexpected token <` then that means I got back some HTML instead of JSON but I don't know what the `P` means in this error.

I upgraded Node. Could that be the cause of the error? What exactly breaks proxy?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at what the _actual response_ you get back is? It might also contain headers that show you which server is actually responding to the request; does FastAPI's server log show a 200 response?

Comment: @MatsLindh Hi, I think it was the most recent node version that was causing the problem. I did some experimentation and long story short, when node was the most recent (v17) that 500 error code showed up. I downgraded and when I used v16.14.2, the problem is gone. I am not 100% but I think my node was 16 something before I did the update to 17.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Node `v17.x.x` was causing problems with my proxy. I downgraded to `v16.14.2` (which was approximately the version that I had before the update/upgrade) and the problems are gone.
I am going to see how it goes but something about node `v17` is causing problems with proxy.